# How do i cash the money from my NiceHash account to Paypal or European Bank account?

Tags: banks, money-transfer, cash, wire-transfers, nicehash

In my nicehash i have balance of 100 Euro. 
How do i cash the 100 Euro now to Paypal or my European bank account or do receive via Westurn Union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.nicehash.com/help/how-can-you-use-earned-bitcoins:

> Once you receive your payments in your personal wallet, you can:
>
> - transfer Bitcoins to Bitwala and pay your bills in EUR or transfer EUR to your bank account
> - use online exchanges like Coinbase, Bitstamp, Kraken and others to directly exchange bitcoins to EUR or USD and then transfer EUR or
>     USD to your bank account
> - also buy various goods directly with bitcoins, for example, computer equipment in CaseKing computer shop
>     transfer bitcoins to EUR or USD on pre-paid Credit Cards via CoinsBank service
>
> Of course, there are a lot of other options on how to use, spend and
>   convert your Bitcoins, simply search the Web for other options or ask
>   your retail/online shop whether they accept bitcoins as a payment
>   option.

Comment: I need easy/quick/safe reliable bitcoin to CASH options so that all my currency stays as bitcoin and from there i pay to paypal, ebay, amazon or banks

Comment: All those parties you mention, i.e. "paypal, ebay, amazon or banks" do not deal directly with Bitcoin or any other cryptocurrency. So you would need some kind of interface. StackExchange doesn't like direct product recommendations, but it may make sense that you start looking for a prepaid VISA or Mastercard which can be loaded with Bitcoins. Please be careful as there has been strange things going on with this kind of cards in the past. You will find several offers using Google.

Comment: I signed up Bitwala but they are not available yet to get started. So i should try Coinbase right? But i will have to pay exchange transfer rates?